# How to batch process hundreds of videos?

Tags: video, conversion, automation, workflow, avchd

I have hundreds of videos in storage I need to distribute online.  I'd like to do the following for each clip:

1. Add a pre-roll video
2. Process the audio (audio leveling, generic hiss/noise reduction for speaking (no music or other sound))
3. Add a title overlay at the beginning and end (could be same for all videos, but would like to pull from a spreadsheet to individualize each video if easily accomplished)
4. Convert video from AVCHD 1080p24 to format(s) suitable for Youtube and Vimeo with as little loss of quality as possible.

While static overlays are fine, it would be nice if things were animatable to add a bit more interest to the final product.

I'm a programmer, so I'm fine with scripting.  My primary video system is an older windows 7 64 bit machine with a quad-core i7 and 16GB RAM.  I'd be fine turning it into a linux machine temporarily if there are better workflows in that environment. I also have a quad core i7 OS X laptop with 16GB memory, but the disk is slower. There's no particular deadline, so if chewing through these videos slowly can be done cheaply, then that's better than paying for quick conversion, but speed would be nice, particularly if I can task multiple machines to the conversion easily on my network.

I'd prefer not to spend more money, but if there's software that can help me out significantly then buying the correct software might be acceptable.

How do I accomplish this task without spending months individually editing each video once or twice a day?

Comment: I'm not a programmer but I think this is all possible using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net). Here are examples for a [pre-roll video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files), [audio noise reduction](http://www.zoharbabin.com/how-to-do-noise-reduction-using-ffmpeg-and-sox), [text overlay](http://superuser.com/questions/567606/multiple-effect-overlays-with-ffmpeg) and [convert AVCHD](http://pvdm.xs4all.nl/wiki/index.php/Convert_an_AVCHD_/_MTS_file_to_MP4_using_ffmpeg)

Comment: As I'm not familiar with the CLI very well I have no clue on how to string that all together into a nice script, so won't post it as an answer.

Comment: @BartArondson I think that's an excellent answer, though, and gets me enough information to get started.  Add it as an answer so I can accept it, and thanks!

Comment: I've been looking in to this as well.  I have been working on a system using some .Net libraries to build a tool around but I can't recall the name of it currently.  It was free for non-commercial use (non-commercial meaning you aren't selling the software, not that you aren't making videos for commercial purposes).  I will post later with the name of the product as it seemed relatively easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve all your goals using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net), these are command line tools for video and audio processing respectively.

I can not provide you with a ready to roll solution, but here are examples for a [pre-roll video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files), [audio noise reduction](http://www.zoharbabin.com/how-to-do-noise-reduction-using-ffmpeg-and-sox), [text overlay](https://superuser.com/questions/567606/multiple-effect-overlays-with-ffmpeg) and [conversion from AVCHD](http://pvdm.xs4all.nl/wiki/index.php/Convert_an_AVCHD_/_MTS_file_to_MP4_using_ffmpeg).

Answer (score 1):

Quite an expensive solution: [Sony Vegas Pro](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/vegaspro) + [Transcoder](http://vegasaur.com/transcoder) plugin can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Draft that we bundle with Deadline was built to do this sort of thing. Full disclosure: I work for the company that makes this.

Docs for Draft's fancy features.
http://docs.thinkboxsoftware.com/products/draft/1.5/Documentation/#basic-operations

Minimum cost is about $200 US at the moment for one machine, but you get a huge amount of process automation here.